# Memory leak Python, lists inside for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-leaks

I wrote a simple snippet of code to process a text file that contains one phrase per line with PoS tagged words (e.g. I/noun am/verb) and I want to extract the word and the tags separately:

```
splitted_sentences = []
splitted_pos = []

with open("my_path", "r") as tagged_sentences:
    for sentence in tagged_sentences:
        curr_sentence = []
        curr_pos = []
        for tag in sentence.strip().split(" "):
            splitted_tag = tag.split("/")
            word = splitted_tag[0]
            pos = splitted_tag[1]
            curr_sentence.append(word)
            curr_pos.append(pos)
        splitted_sentences.append(curr_sentence)
        splitted_pos.append(curr_pos)
```

The code works as expected but however, memory ram consumption never stops increasing while the loop is executing well above expected (text file is ~100MB and RAM reaches a peak consumption of 5GB). I have tried using some memory profiling tools and it looks like I'm creating thousands of list references (probably curr_sentence and curr_pos lists). What is the proper way of tackling this problem whitout running into memory leaks?

Comment: Run it with a very small file (e.g. 3 sentences). Use the debugger to step through each line and look at the variable contents. Use a real IDE like PyCharm.

Comment: You can check `enumerate(tagged_sentences)` to understand how quick the memory grows over your lines.

Comment: Is this all the code? This part seems to be correct, and should not generate such a problem - but also, is your text file well formed?  Large portions without "/" or " " could also trouble this snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`splitted_sentences` is a list of lists of strings. Memory overhead for lists is ~70 bytes, and ~40 bytes for strings. Assuming average word/POS is 5 bytes and average sentence is 10 word/pos pairs, 100MB file is 1M sentences * 10 words * 1 string = (1M * 70) * (10 * 40) = 28Gb of memory if all strings were unique. Apparently, many of them are not, but this memory consumption could be explained without memory leaks.

My approach to this problem would be sequential processing. I doubt you really need all this data in memory at the same time. Replacing the main loop with a generator could be a game changer:

```
def sentence_gen(fname):
    for sentence in open(fname, 'r'):
        yield [pair.split("/", 1) for pair in sentence.strip().split()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Move curr_sentence and curr_pos outside of your for loop. Then you can clear instead of creating new ones. My guess is that, for some reason, the curr_sentence and curr_pos lists are not being deleted at the end of the for loop.

By moving those lists outside of the for loop, you will not create new ones on each iteration.

Comment: Marat's answer looks better than mine. :)